# Per day and per developer Graph of Code commit volume

Tags: git

What Git tool can be used to display a graph of code volume per developer per day?

I want to see developer's daily LOC for a Git repository.

Comment: I wrote [git-graphs](https://github.com/choroba/small-scripts/blob/master/git-graphs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to track how many lines of code were added between commits:

```
# find your last reference commit and the desired comparison one
git diff --stat <commit-1> <commit-2>

# or 
git diff --shortstat <commit-1> <commit-2>
```

#### `git diff`

> **`--numstat`**
>   Similar to --stat, but shows the number of added and deleted lines in decimal notation and pathname without abbreviation, to make it more machine friendly. For binary files, outputs two - instead of saying 0 0.
>
> **`--shortstat`**
>   Output only the last line of the --stat format containing total number of modified files, as well as number of added and deleted lines.